# fun.y and stat_summary stopped working in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used to run this code all the time to get the sum of 'n' at the top of my bar chart.

Now I get the follow errors:

> **Ignoring unknown parameters: fun.y**
>
> **No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`**

```
count %>%
ggplot(aes(x = date, y = n, group = class, fill = class)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text_repel(
    aes(label = stat(y), group = date), 
    stat = 'summary', fun.y = sum, vjust = -1
  )
```

[The ggplot no longer 'sums' the data and ignores the vjust](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP4YO.png)

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem - it appears to have done so - you can "accept" it by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 7):

This is a change in the API of `ggplot2` release with `ggplot2 3.3.0`. From the docs:

> fun.ymin, fun.y, fun.ymax    Deprecated, use the versions specified above instead.

Simply switch to `fun`.

```r
library(ggrepel)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  count(gear, cyl) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(gear), y = n, group = factor(cyl), fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text_repel(
    aes(label = stat(y), group = factor(gear)), 
    stat = 'summary', fun = sum, vjust = -1
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Super helpful! Thank you so much.